# How to use redshift's LISTAGG to create new columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm using Redshift's `LISTAGG` function to group tables by pairs:

```
SELECT id, LISTAGG(data, ', ') FROM ... GROUP BY 1;
```

This transforms tables like:

```
1    "data_A"
1    "data_B"
2    "data_C"
2    "data_D"
```

To:

```
1    "data_A, data_B"
2    "data_C, data_D"
```

However, this means that we still have two columns, but it would be nice to create three columns from the data:

```
1    "data_A"    "data_B"
2    "data_C"    "data_D"
```

Assuming *we know* that we can only have two items per id, can such a three column scheme be implemented in Redshift, using `LISTAGG` or some other function combination? As an added bonus, can we sort the data items in the columns, so that the data in the left column is smaller than the data in the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `listagg()`, you can just use aggregation.  Because you want two values, `min()` and `max()` work:

```
SELECT id, MIN(data), MAX(data)
FROM ...
GROUP BY 1;
```

If you could have only one value for a given `id`, you can phrase this as:

```
SELECT id, MIN(data),
       (CASE WHEN MIN(data) <> MAX(data) THEN MAX(data) END)
FROM ...
GROUP BY 1;
```

This puts `NULL` into the third column, if there is only one value for `data`.

Comment: Thank you! forgot about that option.